# Display only result > 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I face a problem with the result on my script.

My formula for MARGIN is `((plnamt-(ibhexc/ibhand))/plnamt)*100`.

I want to display only result > 2. How to do this? Please help.

This my script:

```
select 
a.plnitm,a.plnstr,max(a.plncdt),max(a.plnndt),max(a.plnamt),max(a.plnevt),b.idept,c.ibhand,c.ibhexc,
decimal((c.ibhexc/c.ibhand),12,4) as AVG_COST,
decimal(((((max(a.plnamt)-(c.ibhexc/c.ibhand))/(max(a.plnamt))))*100),12,4) as MARGIN

from prcpln a
inner join invmst b on a.plnitm = b.inumbr
inner join invbal c on a.plnitm = c.inumbr and a.plnstr = c.istore and c.ibhand <> 0
where a.plnstr = ''14006''

group by a.plnitm,a.plnstr,b.idept,c.ibhand,c.ibhexc
order by a.plnitm
```

Comment: use `HAVING()`.

Comment: having() doest work for me , i dont know why, sorry

Comment: please show the query that `doest work`

Comment: i use this 
having (((((max(a.plnamt)-(c.ibhexc/c.ibhand))/(max(a.plnamt))))*100)) > 2

error : The keyword HAVING was not expected here.  A syntax error was detected at keyword HAVING.  The partial list of valid tokens is FOR USE......

Comment: Did you wrote `HAVING` statement between `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`?

Comment: group by a.plnitm,a.plnstr,b.idept,c.ibhand,c.ibhexc
having (((((max(a.plnamt)-(c.ibhexc/c.ibhand))/(max(a.plnamt))))*100)) < 2
order by a.plnitm

And it works

Comment: So, you said you wanted >2 and then you used <2? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplistically, for situations like this, you can take your query and put it inside a cte:

```
WITH q AS (

select 
a.plnitm,a.plnstr,max(a.plncdt),max(a.plnndt),max(a.plnamt),max(a.plnevt),b.idept,c.ibhand,c.ibhexc,
decimal((c.ibhexc/c.ibhand),12,4) as AVG_COST,
decimal(((((max(a.plnamt)-(c.ibhexc/c.ibhand))/(max(a.plnamt))))*100),12,4) as MARGIN

from prcpln a
inner join invmst b on a.plnitm = b.inumbr
inner join invbal c on a.plnitm = c.inumbr and a.plnstr = c.istore and c.ibhand <> 0
where a.plnstr = ''14006''
group by a.plnitm,a.plnstr,b.idept,c.ibhand,c.ibhexc

)
SELECT * FROM q WHERE margin > 2
ORDER BY q.plnitm
```

This is similar to the advice to use HAVING - a HAVING is a "where clause that is done after a GROUP BY"

A cte is a way of taking some calculated block of data and giving it an alias that can be used just like a table. I wanted to answer this way to point out to you that queries don't have to be formed purely from tables; tables are just blocks of data (with a name), and the output from a select is also "just a block of data" that can be given a name (by use of a cte or subquery) and then used just like a table is

Comment: Thank you @caius for this. i might use this code .